# White Screen(OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I am new to OpenGL and i want to draw a simple triangle on screen with my shader. I set up buffers and wrote a shaders but it doesn't seem to work. It gives white screen, i tried to change glCreateBuffer with glGenBuffer and screen turned to black screen. I want to create&compile shaders in one function called createAndCompileShader(...), buffers are defined in main function.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

static unsigned int createAndCompileShader(const char* vertexShader, const char* fragmentShader) {

    unsigned int fragmentShaderr = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    unsigned int vertexShaderr = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vertexShaderr, 1, &vertexShader, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderr, 1, &fragmentShader, NULL);

    glCompileShader(vertexShaderr);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderr);

    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(program, vertexShaderr);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShaderr);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    

    return program;
}


int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    float vertexPositions[6] = {
             -0.5, -0.5,
             0.0, 0.5,
             0.5, -0.5
    };


    const char* vertexShader = "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "gl_Position = position;\n"
        "}\n";

    const char* fragementShader = "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";

    unsigned int program = createAndCompileShader(vertexShader, fragementShader);

    glUseProgram(program);

    unsigned int buffer;

    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    //glCreateBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float)*2 , 0);

  
    //std::string vertexShader;
    //std::string fragmentShader;

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0 ,3);

        /*glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex2f( 0.0, 0.5);
        glVertex2f( 0.5, -0.5);
        glEnd();*/

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteProgram(program);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do some error handling in your `createAndCompileShader`

Comment: I tried that, but i didn't see any error about syntax etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment shader input layout locations qualifiers are not provided in GLSL 3.30. You have to switch to GLSL 4.10 or remove the layout location in the fragment shader:

<s>`layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;`</s>

```c
in vec4 position;
```

Furthermore you missed the specification of the fragment shader output `color`.

```c
#version 330 core
in vec4 position;
out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I recommend to use [Raw string liters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```cpp
const char* fragementShader = R"(#version 330 core
in vec4 position;
out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
})";
```

Check if the shader compilation succeeded and if the program object linked successfully.
If the compiling of a shader succeeded can be checked by [`glGetShaderiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml) and the parameter `GL_COMPILE_STATUS`.
If the linking of a program was successful can be checked by [`glGetProgramiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml) and the parameter `GL_LINK_STATUS`.
(See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59235204/light-shows-but-the-cube-does-not-appear/59236020#59236020) question.)

---

If you use a core profile OpenGL Context, the the default [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) is not valid. Create a named VAO:

```cpp
unsigned int VAO;
glCreateVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

unsigned int buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float)*2 , 0);
```

---

*GLEW* has to be initialized by `glewInit()`. See [Initializing GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html):

```cpp
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glewInit();
```

Comment: @Bcrx It works fine for me. Just copy the shader code.

Comment: It worked!, little inattention, i'll be more careful after this, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have frequently used layout location qualifiers for vertex shaders, glsl 3.30, without any problems. Only in Visual Studio using an extension for glsl support was I presented with warning, but I just ignored it and it still worked fine. You wouldn't happen to know why that could be?

Comment: @ワイきんぐ Please read the answer: **Fragment shader** input layout locations qualifiers [...]. Of course vertex shader input layout qualifiers are valid in GLSL 3.30

Comment: That's weird, because I always got this warning for vertex shaders. But thanks!